# Subnet mask for two networks

Tags: networking, subnet

If we have the IP address 192.168.1.2 with subnet mask 255.255.255.252 then there are four addresses in the network and we can refer to the address as 192.168.1.2/30

Are addresses outside this range also diveded into subnets of four IP addresses eg. 192.168.1.(4 to 7)?

Is it valid to have an address as 192.168.1.**2**/30 at the same time as 192.168.1.**6**/30 and both use 255.255.255.252 as subnet?

My confusion is that if I look at the Six in 192.168.1.**6** it has a binary value 0000 0110 which seems like would be /29 instead of /30.

Answer (score 0):

The `/30` refers to how many bits out of the 32 available in an IPv4 address form the network part of the address (or, formatted as a dotted decimal netmask, `255.255.255.252`).

So with your suggested `192.168.1.6/30`, it would be the same as `192.168.1.2/30`: you would have 30 bits of network address (`^`) and 2 bits left for the host (`-`):

```
1100 0000  1010 1000  0000 0001  0000 0010
1100 0000  1010 1000  0000 0001  0000 0110
^^^^ ^^^^  ^^^^ ^^^^  ^^^^ ^^^^  ^^^^ ^^--
```

`192.168.1.6/30` refers to the four addresses `192.168.1.4-192.168.1.7` which share an initial 30 bits.

`192.168.1.6/29` would be the subnet consisting of the eight addresses `192.168.1.0-192.168.1.7` which share an initial 29 bits.